# CMake generates error with project statement in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm trying to load a project into CLion (using Windows 10 and Cygwin).  When CLion processes the `CMakeLists.txt` file, the following errors are generated

```
C:\Users\doobop\.CLion2017.2\system\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/m/stream
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:180 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:175 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:170 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)


CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineRCCompiler.cmake:55 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/Platform/CYGWIN-GNU.cmake:50 (enable_language)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/Platform/CYGWIN-GNU-C.cmake:2 (__cygwin_compiler_gnu)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/doobop/.CLion2017.2/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.8.2/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:48 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (project)
```

What is at line 12?

```
project( SWP )
```

Why would the project assignment cause all these errors?

Comment: `Why would the project assignment cause all these errors?` - [project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/project.html) isn't a just project assignment. The command also performs a platform checks and compiler detection. You may see that from the names of CMake modules caused the errors. Possible reasons include broken installation or setup of CLion, CMake or Cygwin. Also, possible reason could be wrong commands issued before the `project()` call.